# Источник события

Tags: android, события, android-broadcastreceiver

Вот есть события, `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON` и `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF`. Есть ли возможность узнать, по какой причине произошли события (пользователь разбудил телефон, звонок входящий или какой-нибудь WhatsApp свое окно нарисовал и зажег экран). Чтобы отличить ситуацию когда моей программе надо реагировать, а когда нет.

Это все же проблема. Сейчас вот выяснился серьезный косяк - у человека настроен будильник, а при его срабатывании (зажигается же экран), выскакивает мое приложение, будильник уходит в фон и не звонит (видимо считает что хозяин его выключил?) И, говорят, такая же беда когда музыку слушают - тоже, когда трек заканчивается (наверное плеер тоже экран зажигает), выскакивает мое приложение. Как научить приложение просыпаться только при зажигании экрана от кнопки?

Comment: вы можете в дебаге посмотреть все, что приходит вам в интенте. Лично я сомневаюсь, что приходит причина.

Comment: metalurgus - вот я тоже не смог найти, решил спросить. Может есть какой-то способ различить - нажатие кнопки пользователем было или это другая программа какая-то включила экран...

Comment: @Alexander вы, как автор сообщения, можете откатить правку в один клик - откат в истории изменений. Или просто вернуть "привет" обратно простым редактированием (что лучше, если очень хочется оставить именно приветствие). Просто местные правила оформления подразумевают отсутствие приветствий. Вплоть до того, что на enSO они вырезаются автоматически. "Здравствуйте - Здесь не здороваются! - Ну извините.... - И не извиняются!" давно стало местным мемом. Не стоит так бурно на это реагировать :)

Comment: PashaPash - хорошо, не буду :) Не принято, так не принято.